# Symfony2 trans_default_domain multiple xlf files

Tags: symfony, twig

I am trying to bring some organization to the translation files in **Symfony2**. I don't want one huge translation file with thousands of entries. I d rather split the xlf files up and import with the command

```
{% trans_default_domain 'add-user' %}
```

but some of the pages have common text, like "filter", or "show all entries" etc...

what I would like to do is something like this

```
{% trans_default_domain 'add-user', 'global-texts' %}
```

just chain two or three different xlf files in one twig template.

But it doesn't work. Is there another way or solution to this problem? How do you organize big projects with thousands of translation tags?

Any hints and tips are appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

With `trans_default_domain` you configure the **default** domain. You can still pass the domain as the second argument to `|trans[choice]`:

```
{{ 'hello'|trans({}, 'the_domain') }}
```

Or using the `from` keyword in the `trans[choice]` tags:

```
{% trans from 'the_domain' %}hello{% endtrans %}
```